# How to merge arrays in alternating pattern without duplicates

Tags: java

I'm currently learning in school but am unable to complete this part of the assignment.
An explanation with the use of for loops would be greatly appreciated.

The numbers should be added to the merged array in an alternating pattern: first from list 1, then from list 2, then list 1 again, etc. If a number in one of the arrays already appears in the merged array, then it should be ignored, and the program should alternate to the other list again. For example, if the first list begins 1 2 3 10, and the second begins 3 4 5 8, then the merged list would begin 1 3 2 4 5 10 8.

Because the number of elements in the merged array is unknown, its size should be set to the maximum possible number of elements it should contain, and after all elements which should form the merged array appear, any remaining unfilled spaces in the array should be 0. The first 0 encountered in the array should signal the end of the “actual” elements of the array, and therefore the 0s at the end of the array should not be printed by your program.

Comment: Where are you struggling? This comes across as "do my homework for me" despite that potentially not being the case. It looks like you haven't even attempted to merge the arrays.

Comment: @mistahenry I have edited my attempt to merge arrays but struggled with removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use a `HashSet` to remember which number you have already inserted into the array. For each number, you first check if the hash set already contains the number; if not, you add it to both the array and the set. For large inputs, this is much faster than checking the result array for each number. O(n*log(n)) or so (depending on how well the HashSet works for your input) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am currently learning in school and have not learned HashSet yet. Would you be able to explain how I would be able to do it with for loops?

Comment: @Bubble In this case, just search the result array if it already contains the number... Googles `java array contains` to find some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

@bubble

An example using a Set is very simple - however your teacher is asking for
an alternate list:

```
Integer[] one = new Integer[] {10,2,3,1};
Integer[] two = new Integer[] {3,8,5,4}; 

List<Integer> li_one = Arrays.asList(one); // First convert the arrays to a list
List<Integer> li_two = Arrays.asList(two);

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

set.addAll(li_one); 
set.addAll(li_two);

System.out.println("The unique list is: " + set);
```

Answer (score -1):

A HashSet was my first idea too, but the order of storing values depends
one hash values. The ... teacher likes to have alternating values which
I dont like to comment - because it is a really strange request.

Following code prints: merged list is: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 10, 8]

```
int[] one = new int[] {1,2,3,10};
int[] two = new int[] {3,4,5,8}; 

int one_len = one.length;
int two_len = two.length;

List<Integer> merged = new ArrayList<>();

int oneval,twoval;

for (int i = 0;i < one_len;i++)
{
    oneval = one[i];
    if (!merged.contains(oneval))  merged.add(oneval);

    if (i < two_len)
    {
        twoval = two[i];
        if (!merged.contains(twoval))  merged.add(twoval);
    }
}
if (two_len > one_len)
{
   for (int i = one_len; i < two_len;i++)
   {
       twoval = two[i];
       if (!merged.contains(twoval))  merged.add(twoval);
   }
}
System .out.println("merged list is: " + merged);
```